# Is signed to unsigned conversion, and back, defined behaviour for integers?

Tags: c++, c++11, integer, type-conversion, undefined-behavior

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  uint32_t i = -64;
  int32_t j = i;

  std::cout << j;
  return 0;
}
```

Most compilers I've tried will create programs that output `-64`, but is this defined behaviour?

- Is the assignment of a signed integer to and unsigned integer `uint32_t i = -64;` defined behaviour?
- Is the signed integer assignment `int32_t j = i;`, when `i` equals `4294967232`, defined behaviour?

Comment: defined for unsigned but not signed

Comment: There is a subtule distinction, overflow of a signed artihmetic operator (which is what the so-called duplicate is about) is undefined behaviour but overflow when converting to a signed type is implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: This question originally had a title which confusingly referred to _signed overflow_, but the question as is clear from the code sample is really about conversion (including cases which the exact value isn't representable, which isn't usually referred to as "overflow"). I've fixed the title, but it means that the linked duplicate is not an answer for this question. The accepted answer is correct, however.

Comment: reopened - the "duplicate" was an unrelated question

Answer (score 9):

For unsigned integer out-of-range conversion, the result is defined; for signed integers, it's implementation-defined.

> #### C++11(ISO/IEC 14882:2011) §4.7 Integral conversions  [conv.integral/2]
>
> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). —end note ]
>
> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

This text remains the same for C++14.

Comment: Where do I check what my implementation has defined it as?

Comment: @Sancho You mean for the implementation-defined behavior, how to check how it's defined in your implementaion? I think you can try to see the manual, or better, there are some options to control it. After all, it's **implementation-defined**.

Comment: I mean, how do I check what my implementation has defined this behaviour to be.

Comment: **1.3.10** implementation-defined behavior: behavior, for a well-formed program construct and correct data, that depends on the implementation and that **each implementation documents** (emphasis mine).

Comment: @Sancho Again, that' not something that you can find in the C++ standard, checking the manual of your compiler may be helpful.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik and Yu Hao, I know I need to check the implemenation. I'm asking, *where* is that documented by the implementation. Is it in `man gcc`? I couldn't find it there. Is it in a header file somewhere? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: @Sancho `man gcc` has too little information, try the manual online:http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/  I haven't found it yet though.

Comment: @Sancho gcc will, at certain optimization levels, actually assume that signed integer overflow simply does not occur, and execute dead-code elimination if your code attempts to detect it!  If it does occur, it is going to be platform specific: whatever the hardware does when they run the most efficient operation to convert from unsigned to signed (which, on many (most?) 2s compliment machines, gives you the result you expect).

Comment: @Sancho: Please note that the quote covers conversions.

Comment: This question originally had a title which confusingly referred to signed overflow, but the question as is clear from the code sample is really about conversion (including cases which the exact value isn't representable, which isn't usually referred to as "overflow"). I've fixed the title, but it means that the linked duplicate is not an answer for this question. The accepted answer is correct, however - unfortunately I can't remove my downvote which originally made sense in the context of "overflow".

Comment: @BeeOnRope When that situation occurs you can edit the post yourself (make some trivial formatting change or something) to re-enable voting. If you have enough rep to edit other posts, that is.

Comment: Edited this answer to specify that it is out-of-range conversion , and not overflow. Signed overflow is undefined behaviour , but the code in this question does not invoke overflow.

Comment: @BeeOnRope sorry, I meant you could have edited this answer in order to be able to remove your downvote .   (I assume you were referring to this answer by "the accepted answer", even though it isn't accepted)

Comment: @M.M - you are right, sorry for the confusion! I was able to remove it now since you edited it.

Comment: For GCC, this is documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation) (that’s for C, but the C++ page references this one). [Clang does not document it](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11272), and is therefore not technically a conforming C++ compiler. MSVC documents it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/demotion-of-integers) for C, but I can’t find the equivalent page for C++.

Answer (score 1):

The Standard requires that implementations document, somehow, how they will determine what value to use when an integer is converted to a signed type which is too small to accommodate it.  It does not specify the form such documentation will take.  A conforming implementation's documentation could specify in readable print that values will be truncated and two's-complement sign extended, and then in impossibly small print specify "...except when a program is compiled on the fifth Tuesday of a month, in which case out-of-range conversions will yield the value 24601".  Such documentation would, of course, be less than helpful, but the Standard does not concern itself with "quality of implementation" issues.

In practice, implementations that define the behavior in any fashion other than 100% consistent truncation and two's-complement sign extension are extremely rare; I would not be particularly surprised if in fact 100% of conforming C99 and C11 implementations that are intended for production code default to working in that fashion.  Unfortunately, neither `<limits.h>` nor any other standard header defines any means via which implementations can indicate that they follow the essentially-universal convention.

To be sure, it's unlikely that code which expects the common behavior will be tripped up by the behavior of any conforming compiler.  It's plausible, however, that compilers might offer a non-conforming mode, since that could make certain kinds of code more efficient.  For example, given:

```
int32_t x,i;
int16_t *p;
...
x = ++p[i];
```

If `int` is larger than 16 bits, behavior would be defined in case `p[i]` was 32767 before the code executed.  The increment would yield -32768, the value would be converted to `int16_t` in Implementation-Defined fashion (which is guaranteed to yield -32768 unless an implementation documents something else), and that value would then be stored to both `x` and `p[i]`.

On processors like the ARM which always do arithmetic using 32 bits, truncating the value stored to `p[i]` would cost nothing, but truncating the value written to `x` would require an instruction (or, for some older ARM models, two instructions).  Allowing `x` to receive +32768 in that case would improve efficiency on such processors.  Such an option would not affect the behavior of most programs, but it would be helpful if the Standard defined a means via which code which relied upon behavior could say, e.g.

```
#ifdef __STDC_UNUSUAL_INT_TRUNCATION
#error This code relies upon truncating integer type conversions
#endif
```

so that those programs that would be affected could guard against accidental compilation in such modes.  As yet the Standard doesn't define any such test macro.

Answer (score 1):

It's well defined in C++20, according to [N2218 Signed Integers are Two’s Complement](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2218.htm) and [P1236R1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1236r1.html).

Prior to C++20, this behaviour is the defacto standard. Can assume that it's true in the C++ world from the begining. C++20 just standardize it.